Attribute value html encoded when added to custom tag builder
I'm trying to add an OnClick attribute to a custom tag helper, but the value doesn't render properly. It looks like it gets encoded.
AddAttribute:
icon.AddAttribute("onclick", $"togglePasswordVisible('{this.InputControlName}');");

Page source:
onclick="togglePasswordVisible(&#x27;TesterPass&#x27;);"

How can I keep the formating of the value?

To prevent HTML encoding of attribute value:

Use HtmlString or IHtmlContent
Wrap value: new HtmlString($"togglePasswordVisible('{InputControlName}');")
Add attribute: icon.AddAttribute("onclick", wrappedValue);

This preserves original formatting in output.

@Anastasios3 I tried this: HtmlString hs = new($"togglePasswordVisible('{this.ControlName}');"); and icon.AddAttribute("onclick", hs.Value);, but same issue. Was this how you meant?

@Anastasios3 thank's for your help. One issue is that I can't pass a HtmlString as value, it must be a string. I found TagHelperAttributeList which uses TagHelperAttribute's which allows for some more control of value. But I canæt figure out how to use it with the tag builder

Ok, here's a more casual try:
Hey, for that encoding issue, maybe try this:
var clickStuff = $"togglePasswordVisible('{InputControlName}')";
icon.Attributes.Add("onclick", clickStuff, false);

The false bit tells it not to encode. Might work? Let me know if it doesn't and we can figure something else out!

var stuff = $"togglePasswordVisible("{this.ControlName}");";
icon.AddAttribute(new CustomAttribute("stein", stuff, false));
icon.AddAttribute("stuff", stuff);
        IHtmlContent cont = new HtmlContentBuilder().AppendHtml($"togglePasswordVisible('{this.ControlName}');");
        HtmlString hs = new($"togglePasswordVisible(\"{this.ControlName}\");");
        icon.AddAttribute("onclick", hs.Value);
        icon.AddAttribute("song", cont.ToStringValue());
        icon.AddAttribute(new CustomAttribute("och", stuff, false));




@Anastasios3 this is what I've tried so far. it's weird it just automatically encodes the value without any option out

Looks like the encoding's being super stubborn. Let's try this:

var js = $"togglePasswordVisible('{ControlName}')";

icon.Attributes.Add("onclick", js, HtmlAttributeValueStyle.NoQuotes);


This skips quotes. Might dodge the encoding. Work?
If not, maybe your tag helper's being sneaky. Wanna share more about it?

@Anastasios3 I was just wondering, would it be possible to decode the whole output from the tag helper, before It's written to the html?

@Anastasios3 I cleaned it up and ended up decoding the whole tag. thanks for the help!

Fixed the problem with html decoding the entire tag.
TagHelper:
[HtmlTargetElement("password", Attributes = "name", TagStructure = TagStructure.NormalOrSelfClosing)]
public sealed class PasswordTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    private string _name = string.Empty;

    public override async Task ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        output.SuppressOutput();

        TagBuilder wr = new("div");
        TagBuilder inp = new("input");
        TagBuilder ico = new("i");

        inp.TagRenderMode = TagRenderMode.SelfClosing;
        inp.Attributes.Add("type", "password");
        inp.Attributes.Add("data-visible", "0");
        inp.Attributes.Add("id", this.ControlName);
        inp.Attributes.Add("name", this.ControlName);
        
        ico.AddCssClassRange("icon", "eye", "fa-icon", "far", "fa-eye");
        ico.Attributes.Add("onclick", $"togglePasswordVisible('{this.ControlName}');");

        wr.AddCssClassRange("creator-password-wrap", "flex-start-center");
        wr.InnerHtml.AppendHtmlRange(inp, ico);

        string tag = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(wr.InnerHtml.ToStringValue());

        output.Content.AppendHtml(tag);

        await base.ProcessAsync(context, output);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Name of input control
    /// </summary>
    [HtmlAttributeName("name")]
    public string ControlName { get; set; } = "txtPassword";
}

